# Rasbperry Pi suddenly stopped connecting to WiFi network defined in wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: pi-3, wifi

My Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie has been automatically connecting to a WiFi network defined in my wpa_supllicant.conf file for a few months without a problem. Two days ago, the Pi stopped connecting to the WiFi network without any known changes.

Scanning for networks shows the WiFi network is available `iwlist wlan0 scan`:

```
Cell 02 - Address: D6:D9:19:9A:00:5A
                  Channel:1
                  Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                   Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                   Encryption key:on
                   ESSID:"DiscoPro"
                   Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                             11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                   Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                   Mode:Master
                   Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                   Extra: Last beacon: 10650ms ago
                   IE: Unknown: 0008446973636F50726F
                   IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                   IE: Unknown: 030101
                   IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                   IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                   IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                   IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                   IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C0101FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                   IE: Unknown: 3D1601000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                   IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                       Group Cipher : CCMP
                       Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                       Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                   IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

`sudo wpa_cli` reveals:

```
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="DiscoPro"
<3>Trying to associate with d6:d9:19:9a:00:5a (SSID='DiscoPro' freq=2412 MHz)
<3>CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="DiscoPro" auth_failures=5 duration=60 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` contents:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wireless-power off

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` contents:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="DiscoPro"
        psk="XXXX"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

`wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d` outputs:

```
wpa_supplicant v2.3
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'default' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
ctrl_interface='DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'
update_config=1
country='GB'
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='DiscoPro'
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=2 op=0 soft=1 hard=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x552ccc40
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 09 0d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=6): 04 09 50 6f 9a 09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=5): 7f 50 6f 9a 09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 08 01
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=040e
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0e
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=06
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=1): 06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 0a 07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x552ccc40 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 0a 11
nl80211: Failed to register Action frame processing - ignore for now
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
nl80211: driver param='(null)'
Add interface wlan0 to a new radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=CA (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 17 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 24 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5600 @ 80 MHz 24 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5650-5730 @ 80 MHz 24 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Do not indicate P2P_DEVICE support (p2p_device=1 driver param not specified)
wlan0: Own MAC address: b8:27:eb:bb:61:1c
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
TDLS: TDLS operation supported by driver
TDLS: Driver uses internal link setup
wlan0: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: a78514ab-6089-5e77-8470-8ee7d2081435
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
Using existing control interface directory.
ctrl_interface_group=108 (from group name 'netdev')
ctrl_iface bind(PF_UNIX) failed: Address already in use
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

Failed to add interface wlan0
wlan0: Request to deauthenticate - bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 pending_bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3 state=DISCONNECTED
TDLS: Tear down peers
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
wlan0: Cancelling delayed sched scan
wlan0: Cancelling scan request
wlan0: Cancelling authentication timeout
Remove interface wlan0 from radio phy0
Remove radio phy0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Unsubscribe mgmt frames handle 0xdda444c9 (mode change)
```

And `ps aux | grep wpa_supplicant` gives me:

```
root       430  0.0  0.4   6696  3640 ?        Ss   11:00   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       512  0.0  0.4   7152  3692 ?        Ss   11:00   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
pi        2994  0.0  0.2   4276  2008 pts/1    S+   12:10   0:00 grep --color=auto wpa_supplicant
```

Things I've tried without success:

- Rebooting.
- Ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` without errors.
- Logged into the Pi via VNC to select the network from the GUI. Prompt for a passcode; still does not connect to the WiFi.
- Added `wireless-power off` to the network interface file.
- Confirmed that I'm not getting any low power lighting bolts on the desktop GUI.
- Removed the network from `wpa_supplicant.conf`, reboot. Added the network back, reboot.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps your arp cache is corrupted in either your router or your Pi... what is the output of `sudo arp -v` on your Pi? ... And either reboot your router or clear the arp cache manually on it.

Comment: @RubberStamp only my LTE dongle:  

    `Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
    huawei.setup             ether   14:5f:94:de:98:fa   C                     eth1
    Entries: 1      Skipped: 0      Found: 1`

Comment: Before making changes to a system that has been working reliably, especially with wifi, I'd see if things outside your control might be causing the problem. Perhaps someone new is congesting the spectrum. Have you tried simply moving the RPi closer or checking to see if channel 1 is congested?

Comment: @bostro I wish I could. Unfortunately, this is an off the grid setup that I don't have physical access to during the winter months. I don't think that there's congestion on channel 1 since there are no people within 100 kilometers of this system. I can't really move the device to see if something is blocking the connection until I get access in the summer; however, at the moment the Raspberry Pi is physically next to the WiFi hotspot.

Comment: @RubberStamp I can't clear the arp cache on my WiFi hotspot remotely. Would changing the mac address (or something like that) of the Raspberry Pi so that it looks like a new device connecting to the hotspot be worth a try?

Comment: >Would changing the mac address of the Raspberry Pi ....  If the problem is arp cache corruption on the router, it's unlikely that changing the MAC of the Pi is going to work.  I've had routers that routinely needed to be rebooted due to arp cache problems.  In some cases, the router's table writes past the end of its array... some brands are notorious...  It seems that you have Internet access to the Pi, even though it's a remote unit.  How are you connecting to the remote Pi?

Comment: @RubberStamp The Raspberry Pi has a USB LTE stick which allows me to SSH/VNC into the device. I'm trying to connect to the WiFi of a GoPro to download images. The GoPro has an Arduino attached that turns the GoPro on and off intermittently. I can see the WiFi of the GoPro coming on and off as expected, just not able to connect to its WiFi.

Comment: @RubberStamp I added some new information to my question based on the results of `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d`.  Any insight as to what I should try here? Which file should I try manually removing  `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` or `/var/run/wpa_supplicant/`?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I am running a Tomato router with multiple WLANs, and, come to think of it, all the devices will no longer connect to that specific wifi network, hmm... Must be a router problem.

Comment: For me, it turned out that changing the password on the router was enough to get the devices to reconnect.